# Add md-tooltip/title in md-checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need add tooltip/title in md-checkbox try to do it in a few ways:

1) **First method**

```
`app.controller('FacetExactAfterController', ['angularLoad', '$document', 
    function (angularLoad, $document) {
            $document.ready(function() {
            var a = $document.find('md-checkbox'); 
            a.append( " <md-tooltip>Play Music</md-tooltip>" );        
            });
}]);`
```

But this way I can't get specific md-checkbox and it is find the 6 exists on the page and print me 6 titles.
Tried to find by content not working too.

2) **Second way is by template changing:**

```
app.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put('components/search/facetExact/facet-exact.html', '< CHANGED 
HTML HERE/>')
}])
```

Where the **< CHANGED HTML HERE/>** is the HTML code that I want to replace. Not working too. 
In the second the Goal is add variables: `translate-default="{{::(facet.displayValue || facet.value)}}" translate="{{::$ctrl.facetLabel(facet)}}" translate-attr-title="{{::$ctrl.facetLabel(facet)}}"` for example

Comment: Can you please replicate issue here in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpaOYx)?

Comment: What should I do?